# TargetInvocationException being thrown on TextView used as Item in MvxListview when adding Selector

Tags: android, android-listview, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I'm using a `MvxListView` coupled with a FrameLayout which host a fragment detailing the selected item's information. It worked fine until I needed to load an item from a file and select it programmatically : the selected item I set using `SetItemChecked(position,true)` wouldn't be highlighted anymore.

So I followed the instructions on this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/10791326/3629868 which pointed me to the use of a `Selector` to change the display depending on the state. The problem is that when I add the `Selector` to my `TextView` as in :

```
android:textColor="@drawable/list_item_text_selector"
```

If I try to display my activity I will get a `TargetInvocationException`, see the first lines of the stack below :

```
MvxBind:Error: 10.52 Exception during creation of TextView from type Android.Widget.TextView - exception TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
at System.Reflection.MonoCMethod.InternalInvoke (System.Object obj, System.Object[] parameters) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at System.Reflection.MonoCMethod.DoInvoke (System.Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at System.Reflection.MonoCMethod.Invoke (BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at System.Activator.CreateInstance (System.Type type, BindingFlags bindingAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] args, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture, System.Object[] activationAttributes) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at System.Activator.CreateInstance (System.Type type, System.Object[] args, System.Object[] activationAttributes) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at System.Activator.CreateInstance (System.Type type, System.Object[] args) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Droid.Binders.MvxAndroidViewFactory.CreateView (System.String name, Android.Content.Context context, IAttributeSet attrs) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

I first thought it might be MvvmCross related as I found this topic on SO : [MvvmCross 3.0.14 - MvxListView selection not working in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20332241/3629868) but one comment linked to this issue https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/issues/481 which was fixed in 3.1.1-beta5 and since I'm using v3.1.1 it should not be related.

Here is the code I use :

The `MvxListView` :

```
<Mvx.MvxListView
    android:id="@+id/allSitesDrawer"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="#30ffffff"
    android:dividerHeight="1dp"
    android:background="#111"
    local:MvxBind="ItemsSource SitesSearchResult"
    local:MvxItemTemplate="@layout/mysitelistitem" />
```

**mysitelistitem.axml** from the layout folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        local:MvxBind="Text Name"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textColor="@drawable/list_item_text_selector" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**list_item_text_selector.xml** from the drawable folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item
      android:state_activated="true"
      android:color="@color/item_selected_text"/>
  <item
      android:state_pressed="true"
      android:color="@color/item_selected_text"/>
  <item
      android:state_pressed="false"
      android:color="@color/item_selected_text"/>
</Selector>
```

(Actually I found an answer that could prove to be a satisfying solution (see [How to highlight the selected item in an MvxListView](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18364907/3629868)) but it doesn't use the `Selector` which feels better in my opinion so I'm curious on how to resolve this with a `Selector`.)

Comment: What if you do your selector not on textColor but on background drawable?  I was looking at this example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3592780/selector-on-background-color-of-textview

Comment: @PkL728 I implemented the example you provided, there is no more exception but I don't see any effect of the selector either.. :/

Comment: Ok, so after my brain got refreshed during the weekend I realised the initial reason why I decided to use a `Selector` (item wouldn't be highlighted) was a mistake from my part : I used a bad index to set the selected item... Such a stupid mistake... I don't know why I didn't think of it earlier... Anyway, the question was about using the `Selector` and that particular problem isn't solved so I'll let it open until a satisfying answer is provided. But I'll be moving on with my code so I might not be able to test answers right away.